# Unable to complete Testlink installation

Tags: php, mysql, database, testlink

Processing:sql/mysql/testlink_create_tables.sql

============================================================================== 
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ============================================================================== 
 ==============================================================================

============================================================================== 
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ============================================================================== 
 ============================================================================== 
Failed! - Installation failed!
TestLink setup couldn't install the default site into the selected database. The last error to occur was Table 'testlink.db_version' doesn't exist during the execution of SQL statement INSERT INTO /*prefix*/db_version (version,notes,upgrade_ts) VALUES('DB 1.9.14', 'TestLink 1.9.14',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())

Comment: Data base, PHP , Apache server, Admin rights for DB all exist but unable to complete the setup. its a fresh installation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved the issues using following steps.

1. Navigate to the `\testlink-code-testlink_1_9\install\sql\mysql` folder and open file `testlink_create_tables.sql`
2. Modify `creation_ts` datetime NOT NULL default 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' as creation_ts` datetime NOT NULL default '2016-11-30 11:26:36'.
3. There should not be two column with default 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. If available change the default value '2016-11-30 11:26:36' instead of 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
4. Provide proper database credential and proceed.
   Hope it will work!

Comment: 1. All most all the tables have creation_ts. Should i change all? 2. my `creation_ts` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP looks like this

Comment: In every table if there is more than one CURRENT_TIMESTAMP then you need to change those as '2016-11-30 11:26:36'. Only one CURRENT_TIMESTAMP column can be available in the table.

Comment: I had to manually execute testlink_create_tables.sql on my machine after this.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this is to install mysql 5.6 or newer. This happens in older versions of mysql such as 5.5 that don't support multiple default values for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.